# Irreducible polynomial over C[X, Y]

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory

Is $f_d(X, Y) =X^d+Y^d+1$ is irreducible as a polynomial over complex numbers for $d>1$ and $d$ natural? If not, there exists a irreducible polynomial of any degree? Because that is what I'm looking for...

Comment: Consider $d=1$, then $f(x,y)=x+y+1$, is irreducible. The condition should be $d>1$.

Comment: Have you reached a conclusion for any small degrees $d$?

Comment: Hey! I don't see how the first part of my question is related with the $X^n-Y^m$ question. It's a particular case that i don't see? Otherwise it seems a bit unfair to flag my question as a duplicate

Comment: I only tried to show for small $d$ by brute force (i.e suppose that $f$ can be written as a product of two polynomials). I not an algebra specialist so that im asking for a more elegant solution that i can learn from.

Comment: @Hector $d \geq 1$ *

Comment: Oh Yes, exactly